# POI Java word formato hoja

Tags: java, apache-poi

¿Como puedo asginarle a word que me cree la hoja horizontal?, por defecto me la crea vertical

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
def doc = document.getDocument();
def body = doc.getBody();

def section = body.getSectPr();

if(!section.isSetPgSz()) {
    section.addNewPgSz();
}

def pageSize = section.getPgSz();
pageSize.setOrient(STPageOrientation.LANDSCAPE);
```

Pero tengo este error:

```
Cannot invoke method addNewPgSz() on null object
```

Comment: Hablamos de documentos Word o de  una *worksheet* en Excel? porque HSSF hace referencia a Excel, pero hablas de Word

Comment: gracias, me confundi queria decir XWPFDocument

Answer (score 0):

Puedes cambiarlo de esta forma:

```
Sheet sheet = document.createSheet("new sheet");
sheet.getPrintSetup().setLandscape(true);
```

Comment: perdona queria para word, acabo de modificar mi post

Comment: En ese caso tienes bastantes respuestas en SO en ingles [como por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20188953/how-to-set-page-orientation-for-word-document)

Comment: grcias por tu respuesta, he modificado mi post ya que sigo sin conseguirlo

Comment: En esa pregunta, en la respuesta aceptada pone que hay que darle un width y height para que se convierta en landscape, no vale solo con la propiedad. Revisalo bien.

Comment: si tb lo añadi pero obtengo un error antes